# iPhone - bug with image and text sending over bluetooth

Tags: iphone, ios, image, bluetooth, gamekit

I have a problem with the `GameKit` framework. In my app, I want to send a text or an image. Now, when I send an image from `UIImagePicker`, it works well. When I send text, it does not show the same `UIAlertView` for images, with no image. Here is the `.h`:

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <GKPeerPickerControllerDelegate, GKSessionDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> {
    GKSession *currentSession;
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtMessage;
    IBOutlet UIButton *connect;
    IBOutlet UIButton *disconnect;
    GKPeerPickerController *picker;
    UIImagePickerController *imgPicker;
    BOOL isText;
    UIImage *_image;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) GKSession *currentSession;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *txtMessage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *connect;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *disconnect;
-(IBAction) btnSend:(id) sender;
-(IBAction) btnConnect:(id) sender;
-(IBAction) btnDisconnect:(id) sender;
-(IBAction)chooseImageData:(id)sender;
@end
```

And the `.m`:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize currentSession;
@synthesize txtMessage;
@synthesize connect;
@synthesize disconnect;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [connect setHidden:NO];
    [disconnect setHidden:YES];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)peerPickerController:(GKPeerPickerController *)picker
              didConnectPeer:(NSString *)peerID
                   toSession:(GKSession *) session {
    self.currentSession = session;
    session.delegate = self;
    [session setDataReceiveHandler:self withContext:nil];
    picker.delegate = nil;
    [picker dismiss];
}

-(IBAction) btnConnect:(id) sender {
    picker = [[GKPeerPickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.connectionTypesMask = GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeNearby;
    [connect setHidden:YES];
    [disconnect setHidden:NO];
    [picker show];
}

- (void)peerPickerControllerDidCancel:(GKPeerPickerController *)picker
{
    picker.delegate = nil;
    [connect setHidden:NO];
    [disconnect setHidden:YES];
}   

-(IBAction) btnDisconnect:(id) sender {
    [self.currentSession disconnectFromAllPeers];
    currentSession = nil;
    [connect setHidden:NO];
    [disconnect setHidden:YES];
}

- (void)session:(GKSession *)session
           peer:(NSString *)peerID
 didChangeState:(GKPeerConnectionState)state {
    switch (state)
    {
        case GKPeerStateConnected:
            NSLog(@"connected");
            break;
        case GKPeerStateDisconnected:
            NSLog(@"disconnected");
            currentSession = nil;
            [connect setHidden:NO];
            [disconnect setHidden:YES];
            break;
    }
}

- (void) mySendDataToPeers:(NSData *) data
{
    if (currentSession)
        [self.currentSession sendDataToAllPeers:data
                                   withDataMode:GKSendDataReliable
                                          error:nil];
}
- (void) mySendImageToPeers:(NSData *) data
{
    if (currentSession)
        [self.currentSession sendDataToAllPeers:data
                                   withDataMode:GKSendDataReliable
                                          error:nil];
}

-(IBAction) btnSend:(id) sender
{
    //---convert an NSString object to NSData---
    NSData* data;
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithString:txtMessage.text];
    data = [str dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    [self mySendDataToPeers:data];
}

- (void) receiveData:(NSData *)data
            fromPeer:(NSString *)peer
           inSession:(GKSession *)session
             context:(void *)context {
    //---convert the NSData to NSString---

    if (isText) {
        isText = YES;
    NSString* str;
    str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Messaggio"
                                                    message:str
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    }
    else
    {
        UIImage *tempSentImg = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        _image = tempSentImg;
        UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Immagine"
                                                        message:@"\n\n\n\n\n"
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:_image];
        CGFloat imageHeight = 100;
        CGFloat imageWidth = imageHeight * _image.size.width / _image.size.height;
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(floor((284 - imageWidth)/2), 47, imageWidth, imageHeight);
        [alert addSubview:imageView];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }

}

-(IBAction)chooseImageData:(id)sender {
    [self performSelector: @selector(dialogOtherAction)];
}

- (void)dialogOtherAction {
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                             delegate:self 
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Annulla", @"")
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"Scegli dalla libreria", @""),
                                  NSLocalizedString(@"Scatta una foto", @""),nil];
    actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imgPicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        imgPicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        imgPicker.delegate = self;

        [self presentModalViewController:imgPicker animated:YES];   
     }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imgPicker.delegate = self;
        imgPicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        [self presentModalViewController:imgPicker animated:YES];
    }
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    [actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)imgPicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];    

    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    [self performSelector: @selector(btnImageSend:) withObject: image afterDelay: 1.0];
}
-(IBAction) btnImageSend:(UIImage *)image
{
    //---convert an NSString object to NSData---
    NSData* data;
    data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [self mySendImageToPeers:data];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you have no way of telling what was sent at the receiving end. Initially the "isText" variable is NO. Every time data is received (in receiveData:fromPeer:inSession:context:), if (isText) always fails and the received data is always interpreted as image data.

One way you can solve this is, instead of simply sending the text or image data, you can send a dictionary. Make the following changes to mySendDataToPeers:, mySendImageToPeers: and receiveData:fromPeer:inSession:context:

```
- (void) mySendDataToPeers:(NSData *) data
{
    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"data type" : @"text",
                           @"data" : data};
    NSData *dictData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:dict format:NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0 options:0 error:nil];

    if (currentSession)
        [self.currentSession sendDataToAllPeers:dictData
                                   withDataMode:GKSendDataReliable
                                          error:nil];
}

- (void) mySendImageToPeers:(NSData *) data
{
    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"data type" : @"image",
                           @"data" : data};
    NSData *dictData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:dict format:NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0 options:0 error:nil];

    if (currentSession)
        [self.currentSession sendDataToAllPeers:dictData
                                   withDataMode:GKSendDataReliable
                                          error:nil];
}


- (void) receiveData:(NSData *)dictdata
            fromPeer:(NSString *)peer
           inSession:(GKSession *)session
             context:(void *)context
{
    NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *) [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:dictdata options:0 format:0 error:nil];
    isText = [@"text" isEqualToString:[dict objectForKey:@"data type"]];
    NSData *data = [dict objectForKey:@"data"];

    //---convert the NSData to NSString---
    if (isText)
    {
        NSString* str;
        str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Messaggio"
                                                        message:str
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else
    {
        UIImage *tempSentImg = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        _image = tempSentImg;
        UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Immagine"
                                                        message:@"\n\n\n\n\n"
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:_image];
        CGFloat imageHeight = 100;
        CGFloat imageWidth = imageHeight * _image.size.width / _image.size.height;
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(floor((284 - imageWidth)/2), 47, imageWidth, imageHeight);
        [alert addSubview:imageView];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }

}
```